# Highcharts datalabels Float Number including Zero after dot: x.0 not only x (exact decimals as in inputdata)

Tags: highcharts

If i enter `17.0`for a data value, the datalabels displays only `17` *(the ".0" is missing)*

How to fix that?

**Example:**

`Input: 17.1 -> ok, data.y = 17.1, dataLabel = 17.1`

`Input: 17.0 -> nok: data.y = 17, dataLabel = 17`

(**BTW**: i do not mean do display always one number after dot, ***i need to have the exact value that i got***, so it may also be `17.00` or `17.000`, depending on the source)

In this example, in the tooltip of May, Serie 1, i need 144.0 displayed and in October, Series 2 in need 176.0, i mean the same "value" i see in the data-Array: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/formatter-shared/ (this is the second example linked here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter )

Comment: What have you done.add example to show issue

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple condition inside tooltip's formatter, which will check if number have decimals. If not (e.g. 144), it will add one additional digit (0) as a decimal.

```
if (value.toString().indexOf('.') === -1) {
  value = value.toFixed(1);
}
```

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/k4nvjm29/

Comment: thanks, but it's not what i need, i need exactly the same as in the data-Array, so in the same Chart one Point can be 12.00, another 16.00000 and a third 9.100

Comment: And this is exactly the same way how tooltip in provided example displays values. Modify your data by adding couple extra decimals in some points values to check that it works as you describe you want it to.